# Can I define schema on kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

**I send data and value schema to kafka topic like this:**

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
  --broker-list 10.0.0.0:9092 --topic orders \
  --property parse.key="true" \
  --property key.schema='{"type":"record","name":"key_schema","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int"}]}' \
  --property key.separator="$" \
  --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"id","type":["null","int"],"default": null},{"name":"product","type": ["null","string"],"default": null}, {"name":"quantity", "type":  ["null","int"],"default": null}, {"name":"price","type":  ["null","int"],"default": null}]}' \
  --property schema.registry.url=http://10.0.0.0:8081
```

**then I get this data from kafka for this sink properties:**

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-oracle",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "orders",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.2.3:1071/orac",
    "connection.user": "[redact]",
    "connection.password": "[redact]",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "name": "jdbc-oracle"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "connector": "jdbc-oracle",
      "task": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "sink"
}
```

But I want to get just json from kafka without `value.schema` . if I put kafka topic just this json data

```
{"id":9}${"id": {"int":9}, "product": {"string":"Yağız Gülbahar"}, "quantity": {"int":1071}, "price": {"int":61}}
```

How can I get this data from kafka and put oracle with confluent jdbc sink.

I want to make schema on Kafka Connect side?

And another thing is can I get two different types of data from one kafka topic and it goes two different table on oracle side with jdbc sink.

Comment: You mean, how to produce Avro messages without providing the schema for the payload?

Comment: `plugin.path` doesn't belong in the connector config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a source topic with JSON data that has no schema declared, you *must* add that schema before you can use the JDBC Sink.

Options include:

1. ksqlDB, as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-3qN_tlYR4&t=981s
2. Kafka Connect's *Single Message Transform* capabilities. No SMT ships with Apache Kafka that does this but there are [prototypes out there](https://github.com/purbon/kafka-connect-transformations/blob/master/smt/src/main/java/com/purbon/kafka/connect/converters/JSONConverter.java) that could do this.
3. Other stream processing e.g. Kafka Streams

*Edit*:

> I mean can I define two different jdbc sink to different oracle tables from one kafka topic

Yes, each topic can be consumed by multiple sinks. The [`table.name.format`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#data-mapping) configuration option can be used to route the topic to different table names as required.

Comment: Thanks for answer i understand that must have schema on topic for confluent jdbc sink? And confluent jdbc must one transform from one topic. Am i right

Comment: "confluent jdbc must one transform from one topic." can you explain more clearly what you're asking?

Comment: "must have schema on topic for confluent jdbc sink?" correct.

Comment: I've updated my answer. On StackOverflow you should really post a new question if you have new ones to your original question :)

Comment: thanks for answer, one more thing maybe I am wrong, I just transfer data from kafka to oracle (anydb with jdbc) with jdbc-sink , am i write? ksql or ksqldb is different things ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211622/discussion-between-ersin-gulbahar-and-robin-moffatt).

Comment: Hi , I want to two different sink to 2 different tables and to different  schema types on one kafka topics

Comment: Kafka -> Oracle is Kafka Connect JDBC Sink, yes. ksqlDB (previously called KSQL) is a stream processing technology with which you can do useful (but not mandatory) processing alongside the JDBC sink

Comment: can you enter chat room pls ?

Comment: I choose to use to StackOverflow just for Q&A. If you want to have extended discussion use http://cnfl.io/slack

Comment: ok I join there :) and I want to be sure , ksqldb is just aggregate or doing joins bla bla before jdbc sink transfer data ? jdbc sink the thing that transfer data?

Comment: On point 2 ... JSONConverter and all its schema features are in AK, so do you mean the SetSchemaMetadata SMT isn't there?